# Facebook like charset error

Tags: wordpress, facebook, encoding, character-encoding, facebook-like

I am using geo places theme on WordPress. I've installed Open Graph Tool for WordPress and everything is good except the encoding.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.urate.mn%2Flists%2F782

What I've discovered so far is that when I remove this from header file Facebook thing works good, but it messes up everything on my website:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Answer (score 0):

With that DOCTYPE you are declaring your page as XHTML. Do you know the difference between a valid HTML and a valid XHTML file? If not, just remove it.

BTW, the default encoding for XHTML is UTF-8, for HTML it is harder to tell exactly (theory and practive do not agree in this case) it usually is Latin1.

Comment: I dont know the difference, but when i remove it messes up css and site :(

Comment: I think you should something something about XHTML if you really want to keep using it. The [Wikipedia page on XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) is useful (especially the "Common errors" section), and so is also http://www.alistapart.com/articles/betterliving/